# Edit text not working in android eclipse

Tags: android

I am not able to include edit text field in xml in eclipse.
The error says:

Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

I am using API20: Android 4.4W version for viewing.
How can we change the version of it?

Comment: could u share your xml code here?

Comment: And what you got in your error log ?

Comment: i have faced same issue which is solved after updating eclipse plugin and Android SDK to latest i.e API 20 L preview.

Answer (score 0):

- The SDK Manager allows you to install or update the latest Android
  platform tools. When downloading and installing the ADT Bundle, the
  latest tools should be already availaqble with the bundle; however,
  you may also want to periodically check for available updated
  versions of the SDK/platform tools.

  In Eclipse, select the menu Window->Android SDK Manager. If the Android SDK location was not set up correctly within Eclipse, go to
  Windows-> Preferences->Android,  and set the SDK location field to
  the root of your SDK install directory.
     In the Android SDK manager window, sort by API level, click Deselect All and check the following boxes:
      From Tools:

  Android SDK Platform-tools
       From Android 4.4 (API 19[image: )]:

  Documentation for Android SDK
     From Android 2.3.3 (API 10):

  SDK Platform
     Samples for SDK (optional)
     From Extras:

Comment: I tried i get only API 20:4.4W i don't get other after going to properties what can i do?

Comment: check your sdk vrsion you only install 4.4 you hav to install 4.1.2

Comment: hey you got the soluction or not?

Comment: No i did not get the solution now i deleted the API20:4.4W by going to Android SDK manager but now i don't know how to download other version can you suggest some sites where i can download other API version.

Comment: see i update my answer now u can click on left side check box on particular version and install package

Comment: Actually when i open the Android SDK manager i don't get all the tools i get only Android API 20:4.4W others are not visible i don't get downloaded in the sdk manager

Comment: Now i get all the packages in android sdk manager, but when i click and install the packages, i get like this
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: SocketTimeout Read timed out
Download interrupted: Read timed out
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 8'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think  4.4(the new update android wear) Doesnt support edittext

Go to Window > Android SDK Manager > Android 4.4 > Delete package

Better you create a new project by downloading the version 4.4.2 i.e api level 19.